# Is it a good practice to load HTML via Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am planning to make a website which has completely different header on mobile and Web as it could not be acheived using media queries. So I was planning to use javascript and php to load the header as per the size of the screen using php include.

The code for the following is as follows

```
//Javascript
let header = document.getElementById('headers');
if(window.innerWidth >= 800){
    header.innerHTML =`<?php require_once "./assets/inc/header-web.php" ?>`;
}else{
    header.innerHTML =`<?php require_once "./assets/inc/header-mobile.php" ?>`;
}


//Markup
<div id="headers"></div>
```

I have made two different types of headers and saved it using the names header-web.php and header-mobile.php.

Now I want to know:

1. Is this a good practice to follow or will it cause any issue or bug in my website?
2. Whether this will be a burden on my DOM and will affect my page load?
3. Will it use too much of resources as two files are loaded every time a page is loaded?
4. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: people do it with jQuery all the time

Comment: @JaromandaX : So its fine using vanilla Js right??

Comment: Your example is running in the client, so you aren't able to execute server side code like this anymore.

Comment: @m90 All the server-side code is doing is inserting a string literal into the JS, there are no problems there

Comment: yes, of course - jquery is javascript so you can use "plain" javascript - I just mentioned jQuery because that's how people seem to use jQuery a lot - but the way you are doing it is better than using jQuery AJAX

Comment: @m90 I have tested it ... Its giving me the results that I am expecting. But I have doubt about it being a good practice

Comment: Since you need to check the `.innerWidth` before setting the HTML, I don't see any alternative to doing this with Javascript like you're doing (not that there are any problems with it anyway)

Comment: As an alternative, you could load the heading's html via ajax when the site is loaded.

Comment: Yep, that's an option too, but potential issue with ajax is that it results in a slight delay before the header gets populated

Comment: I would recommend you to use some CMS like Drupal or MVC architecture based frameworks like CakePHP, Laravel etc...If you are new to PHP then CodeIgniter could be the best option to start with....it will take care of the basic best practices!

Comment: In that case you are using PHP as a templating engine for constructing JavaScript, so the tags and comments on this question might be misleading.

In that case though I don't fully understand why you can't simply insert both chunks into the markup and have a media query decide which one to show?

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe partially displaying the common parts of the header and then load the rest via ajax, but it really depends on the structure of the headers.

Comment: @m90 I thought Dom would take much space if I use it directly into markup. That was my first thought !!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Mostly I use a same header and adjust it using css or javascript however in here they are completely different which cannot be controlled by using order in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a good practice to follow or will it cause any issue or bug in my website?

It will not cause any issues for you in a sense that this code will work. However, I wouldn't be glad to see such code during a code review because it violates *separation of concern*. Right now you have backend and frontend code mixed together which turns the code into spaghetti. You will have a hard time debugging your website. A better solution would be to put all the layout logic to Javascript. For instance, having two divs and using JavaScript to show/hide one of them, or putting two text into javascript variables and just using one that fits current width.

Then you could separate backend-code by reading files in a controller class (if you follow MVC) or at the start of your HTML. Something like `$mobileHeader = require(...)`. In your template: `<div id="mobileHeader" style="display: none"><?=$mobileHeader?>>`.

> Whether this will be a burden on my DOM and will affect my page load?

No, PHP happens on server-side so the browser wouldn't know the difference.

> Will it use too much of resources as two files are loaded every time a page is loaded?

No, it's fine resource-wise. You'll have to read those 2 files anyway, but HTML markup is just not the best place to do it.

> Is there any other way to achieve it?

I've answered that as a part of question #1.

### Conclusion

To sum it up, you did a nice piece of code that works fine and is actually quite succinct. You could also improve your code habits by separating logic and representation.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Whether this will be a burden on my DOM and will affect my page load?

Yes, definitely it will increase the page load time.

> 2.Will it use too much of resources as two files are loaded every time a page is loaded?

No, it will not load two files resources. If it is mobile, it loads mobile header, and its all resource files. If it is web, it loads web header, and its all resource files.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think that wether or not is a good practice depends on your personal style. I see people doing it this way many times, and others doing it in very different ways. There's always a new solution for these sort of things.
That said, this way of doing it will actually slow page load, becouse when you are doing `<?php require_once "./assets/inc/header-mobile.php" ?>` you are essentially evaluating a script and inserting into the html the evaluated value. Obviously that depends on how big are your files though.
One other way of achiving this would be to detect the screen width on page load, and then swapping out a template header with one that you download with an ajax (or similar) call, for example.

```html
<div id='header'>loading animation?</div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("load", () => {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 800) {
    fetch(url).then(response =>
      /* swap header */
    )
  } else {
    fetch(otherurl).then(response =>
      /* swap header */
    )
  }
});
```

Example with ES6 using fetch API.